# iMac 8,1 freezes after selecting option to boot from USB

Tags: imac, usb, startup, performance

1 with 4GB of ram and a faulty GPU that shows some glitches at the top of the screen but still works fine and I have it running Linux and I made a bootable USB for Windows 7 using Rufus, and I can bring up the boot menu but when I select the USB flash drive, a 128GB SanDisk Cruzer Glide, it just froze and got stuck at the boot menu.

I also tried an 8GB flash drive to rule out any issues with the USB drive's storage, but with both when I select it to boot from USB, it just freezes and I can still hear the fans running and the hard drive clicking but it freezes and doesn't do anything except stay at the boot menu.

I've tried everything, including testing both MBR and GPT partitions, but it still didn't work. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps flash drives are counterfeit (hold a little data, but corrupt if more is added) ?

Comment: What's up with the internal drive? Try a safe boot?

Comment: You can not boot the Windows 7 installer from a flash drive on your iMac8,1. Try using a DVD or perhaps the internal drive.